# Not understanding the solution to this rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt { 1+\left(\frac { x }{ \sqrt { 1-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } \right)^{ 2 } } $$

I have done the following:

$$\sqrt { 1+ \frac { x^2 }{  { 1-{ x }^{ 2 } }  } } $$

$$\sqrt{ \frac { 1-x^{ 2 } }{ 1-x^{ 2 } } +\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 1-x^2 } }$$

and ended up with:

$$\sqrt {\frac { 1 }{  { 1-{ x }^{ 2 } }  }} $$

Unfortunately, this is not the correct answer.

Comment: And what is the correct answer? (your answer is correct)

Comment: it is correct, another way of writing the final expression is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ is another option.

Comment: @Vikram That is what the text book saids. How is that the correct form too?

Comment: $[(1-x)(1+x)]^{-1/2}$, too.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: @Vikram Awesome. If you put that in an answer, I'll give you the green check. If that means anything to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\Large\sqrt{1+(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})^2}=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2+x^2}{1-x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

we used : $(\frac{a}{b})^m=\frac{a^m}{b^m}$ (for our problem $m=1/2, a=1, b=(1-x^2) $ )

Have a look at this:http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-laws.html

Comment: That's basically what the OP did.